# Add more tabs in home screen

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

Like Other StackExchange sites, add tabs like featured(with bounty), unanswered, etc. in Home Screen will be easy for Answerers.

Comment: Can you clarify or support with images? As it stands, it doesn't seem clear what you are trying to suggest.

Comment: @nyedidikeke I've added, as an answer, screen shots to show what is missing on Freelancing relative to some other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

All sites have a featured tab, it's just collapsed if there are no bountied questions. The idea is, if there's nothing *in* the tab, there's no reason to show it... so, go put a bounty on a question!

As to the "Unanswered" tab, that exists, too, just not on the main home view. You can find it by clicking on "Questions" instead of the site name.

[image: Questions view of banner]

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other Stack Exchange sites have a "Featured" tab in the question listings, which includes the number of questions with bounties on them in the tab. For example, these shots from ServerFault and SuperUser:

> [image: ServerFault]
>   [image: SuperUser]

Can that tab be added to the Freelancing site? As you can see, it isn't included in our home page question list:

> [image]

<sub>**Note:**</sub>
I wanted to edit the question, but suggested edits, on non-wiki questions, are not allowed in meta. So, I added it as an answer, which the OP, or someone else, can copy into his post, and I can delete the answer, or it can stay as is, to clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks for making the OP clearer. :-)

Comment: He's currently absent from SE due to the academic exam period. Least I could do to keep it from being closed. Seems like a good Q to me. I have speculations as to the answer, but it's probably best to hear from SE for an "official" status.

Comment: You should consider voting the question up in that case so as to show it's a good one which deserves the attention of the community.

Comment: Done that already. My one vote only goes so far. Seeing it back in the neg got me to plan the edit. Then found I couldn't. :( _Ok, answer instead, says I to self. ;P_